# Finding the integral using elementary figures.

Tags: integration

You are given the four points in the plane A=(2,−5), B=(7,1), C=(12,−7), and D=(14,1).

The graph of the function f(x) consists of the three line segments AB, BC and CD.

Find the integral $ \int_2^{14} f(x)dx $ by interpreting the integral in terms of sums and/or differences of areas of elementary figures.

Comment: Is the $f(x)f(x)$ a typo? (It seems odd that the problem would write $(f(x))^2$ in that form).

Comment: What is an "elementary figure"?

Comment: I think they are asking for me to find the area using the area of a triangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

segment $AB$ has slope $\frac 65$ crosses the x-axis at $x=2+5(\frac56) = \frac{41}6$

$$\int_2^7f(x)dx = -\frac12(5)(\frac{29}6)+\frac12(1)(\frac16)
$$

segment $BC$ has slope $-\frac 85$ crosses the x-axis at $x=7+1(\frac58) = \frac{61}8$

$$\int_7^{12} f(x)dx = \frac12(1)(\frac{5}8)-\frac12(7)(\frac{35}8)
$$

segment $CD$ has slope $4$ crosses the x-axis at $x=12+7(\frac14) = \frac{55}4$

$$\int_{12}^{14} f(x)dx = -\frac12(7)(\frac{7}4) + \frac12(1)(\frac14)
$$